# Клик по ссылке и получение IP, MAC. Внесение в БД

Tags: python, django, ip-address, mac-address

Есть приложение на Django. Требуется при клике по ссылке получить IP и MAC, после чего внести эти данные в БД.

КОД для получения IP, работает. А вот для мака найти не могу.

```
import urllib.request
import re
res = urllib.request.urlopen('http://2ip.ru/').read()
print(re.search(b'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', res).group())
```

Как это реализовать?

Хотя бы получение IP при клике, используя вышеприведенный код.

Comment: Дополню- можно также попробовать реализовать вышеописанное через форму: 
<form><input type="button" value="Кнопка"></form>
только незнаю, как передать клик по кнопке на обработку. На C# делал так легко в винформс, но вот в джанго не могу додуматься.

Если никто не знает как в БД пихнуть результат, можно в текстовый файл.

Comment: ну и жесть вы выдумали

Answer (score 2):

В django IP получается из запроса. Ведь потом приложение переедет на сервер. Вот пример функции:

```
def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip
```

Mac можно получить со свича доступа или с роутера. Тут больше зависит от оборудования у пользователя.

Запрос к роутеруб свичу по snmp может выглядель так:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

for (errorIndication,
     errorStatus,
     errorIndex,
     varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(), CommunityData('public'),
               UdpTransportTarget(('адрес роутера', 161)),
               ContextData(),
               ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('RFC1213-MIB::ipNetToMediaPhysAddress'))):

    if errorIndication:
        print(errorIndication)
        break
    elif errorStatus:
        print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                            errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))
        break
    else:
        for varBind in varBinds:
            print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

Выдаст табличку из строк типа:

```
RFC1213-MIB::ipNetToMediaPhysAddress.2.172.20.29.4 = Hex-STRING: 00 26 F2 3F 4B 48
```

Мак `00 26 F2 3F 4B 48` для адреса `172.20.29.4`.

Если известен порт, к которому подключен клиент, то можно запросить конкретный мак, а не всю таблицу. Читайте про "snmp get mac".

На mikrotik-ах можно сделать хотспот. В шаблонах хотспота доступен mac адрес и ip. Отредактируйте форму и её можно встроить iframe для сайта. Чтоб интернет не был ограничен в правила фаервола добавьте ацепт перед правилами хотспота. Смотрите по теме "mikrotik external hotspot portal".